# Fade transition in fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I want to use fullpage for makeing pesonal site.How can i replace fade transition instead of slide effect for changing between to section?

Fullpage.js demo: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842862/fullpage-js-add-slider-fadein-effect.

Comment: This is possible now with the fullpage.js [fading extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fadingEffect.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to override the fullpage transitions with below css, 
Let me know if works

```
.fullpage-wrapper {
width: 100%!important;
transform: none!important;
}

.fp-section {
width: 100%!important;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 0;
transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.fp-section.active {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
}
```

**Update**
 To add a callback to your css transition you have to bind an event to parent `section` like

```
$("yourSection").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
function(e) {

// code to execute after transition ends

});
```

Comment: Interesting approach :)

Comment: Mark answer as yes, Thanks :)

Comment: I was not the one who asked :D

Comment: @M.Tanzil

It works, thanks.
I need this transition start in JS callback (after all animations in section done) have any solution?

Comment: Yeah! you can also do that, for that i will update my answer. :)